# scrollView Not Scrolling to bottom And content view on scroll view was not Scrolling

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: i Have tools on Scrollview in viewcontroller as shown in images]
[image: i Have tools on Scrollview in viewcontroller as shown in images]

i have developed that scroll view as making view of viewController sige 320 & 840 and i placed scrolview and contents

```
   _scrollMainView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
 _scrollMainView.delegate=self;
_scrollMainView.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
_scrollMainView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 850);
```

Comment: This technology world is full of bugs indeed. I am always experiencing bugs like this no matter what technology I am using and your question is difficult to answer by the way.

Comment: but when i activate use autolayouts it scrolling to botton but content view not scrolling

Comment: Then this counts as a bug if you didn't intend that content view not scrolling.

Comment: tell me how to scroll content view

Comment: I would like to, but unfortunately I have no idea how to do that. If I knew then I would answer your question already in first place instead of commenting you. By the way that I am trying to find the solution you are seeking to, but your problem is not easy, so you will have to be patient.

Comment: @ErezZrihen k waiting for ur Solution......

Comment: I know. I got into trouble with his/her problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152744/discussion-between-erez-zrihen-and-savarala).

Comment: What exactly is the question here? I see an image of what I assume is the way it's supposed to look when running the application. You want to simply be able to scroll vertically along those elements, right? From the comments I get you don't use autolayout, which I would strongly advise you do. That bit of code, however seems to indicate you don't know exactly how a scroll view works, but since you're so vague I am not sure. Please clarify your intention, what you have done and what does not work as you expect.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666864/scrollview-not-scrolling-to-the-end-of-the-view

Answer (score 2):

Your scroll view contents one container view and other views (Collection view and labels)

To scroll content as expected your view hierarchy should be like following

1. Main View
2. ScrollView

2.1 Container View

2.1.1 Other Views which you actually want to display in scroll view (in your case collections views and labels should be in container view)

If you don't want to use auto layout then you need to fix frame of scroll view and increase height of container to display all other content

use auto resizing to set scroll view's frame

And if you want to use autolayout then pin scroll view from 4 sides to main view 
 then pin container view from 4 side to scroll view and then add equal heights to scroll view for container

then select height constraint of container view and decrease its priority to 250 
**OR**
add constant height to container view as per your need 
Now you are good to go